# Compiling prolog codes with CHR embedded

Tags: prolog, chr

I have read the user guide for CHRG and I'm having trouble getting my prolog files to work when chrg is embedded. I keep having syntax errors despite following the manual.I am using SWI prolog 6.6.6 and I have also tried SICSTUS Prolog 4.1.2. I have the four source files installed as well and I have :-compile(chrg) as a command in my file. Is there a special way for compiling chrg codes different from prolog codes? I will appreciate any help you can render in this regard,

Comment: I assume that this question refers to [this tutorial](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~henning/chrg/). I have experienced similar problems with CHRG. Which specific compiler error(s) have you encountered?

Comment: CHRG was updated today, so the latest version is compatible with SWI-Prolog 7.2.3 and earlier versions.